# Bot framework - Skype for business

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I need to develop bot framework with Skype for business Channel.
Customer has many software custom on sfb and don't want to migrate ti Microsoft Teams.
Can I develop Microsoft Teams bot and use on Skype for business?
Can I plug bot framework in another way on Skype for business?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/kenakamu/UCWABot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but I wouldn't.

[It's currently possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), but:

> Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated on June 30, 2019.
>
> No new bots will be able to add Skype for Business channel after that date. Existing bots will continue to work until October 31, 2019. Microsoft Teams is the preferred communication tool from Microsoft. Learn how to connect your bot to Microsoft Teams.

There is no other way to use Bot Framework with Skype for Business.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the interoperability of Microsoft Teams and Skype for business? such as in conversations

Comment: Because 1) Teams and SfB use different channels, and 2) interoperability isn't built for bots, I don't believe so. I've suggested an edit to add the microsoft-teams tag, so the Teams team can chime in, but I believe they'd say the same.